# What rear axle do I need?

Tags: mountain-bike, maintenance, axle

I had the chance to buy myself a bargain the other week. It was a Muddy Fox Courier Comp mountain bike – I had one when they first came out. The thing is I need to get a rear axle long enough to fit my wheel. I have just been to Halfords and bought a 10 x 145 mm and it's too short.

I've tried looking all over the internet for the last couple of hours with no joy. So if anybody has any ideas of which type and size of axle I need, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want bike parts, it's usually better to go to a specialist bike shop, rather than to Halfords, which is probably best described as a car parts shop that also sells bikes.

Comment: Thanks mate i just thought they would have all come as standard sizes but me forgetting my bike is from late 80s they dont

Comment: Unfortunately, "The trouble with standards is that there are so many different ones to choose from!" But hopefully somebody will be able to give more precise help than I have.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Helping to find where to buy it from is verging on off-topic because it might not help someone elsewhere in the world. But hopefully we can help identify just what it is you need, to unlock the mystery of tracking it down. Can you start by including photos or measurements of what you have already (old and new) plus how the wheel is held in (axle nuts vs quick release) and how much longer the axle nees to be?

Comment: I’ve taken the liberty of rewording the answer but hopefully it brings the same end result whilst being useful to someone else with the same problem. Change it around if I’ve messed anything up, of course, with the [edit] button. Photos are usually very helpful so see if you can include some too

Comment: I may be able to help but would need some specifics such as what hub type, freewheel or cassette type and sizes for both. Also the rear triangle measurements to the inside and outside of the dropouts. Wheel measurements may also be useful such as width of the wheel and internal diameter of the hub.

Comment: it was my own mistake by not measureing the old one that had snapped wich was 180mm long and i just whent out and bought the longest i could find which was 145 mm but still could do with some advice on where to buy theese parts and its a nut locking type not quick release

Comment: https://hollandbikeshop.com/en-gb/bicycle-wheels/hub-parts/sports-hub-parts/multi-player-rear-axle-180mm-m10-x-1-mm/ https://www.bicyclepartsdirect.com/shop/hub-components/solid-rear-axle-9-5mm-x-24tpi-x-180mm/ https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/OGS0rioeB https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/VeloSolo-M10-Solid-THREADED-Cro-Mo-hub-Hub-AXLE-170mm-180mm-UK-Made-fits-Shimano-/380324808669